# how to make clicked a button with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working at an php project but I have no idea about javascpript but somewhere in my code I needed to make clicked and trigger an event by code Can I do that can you help me?

The code I need to trigger is

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
       $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
       $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
      });

       });
```

My main aim is run this javascpript according coming variable from other page like that

```
        <?php    
           if($_POST['passerr'] == "***Pass format error!!***" ){
           ?>
           <script type="text/javascript">
           $(".btn-slide").trigger("click");
           </script>
      <?php
```

Comment: This is valid code, what is the problem? Here is your EXACT code in a fiddle (working): http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/4LwLT/

Comment: Do you want to run the function within `click()` when `$('.btn-slide')` is clicked? In the title, you say "make clicked," which leads me to believe you are trying to artificially click some button when the user has not organically done so.

Comment: there is no problem in this code problem is I need to trigger or run it but I cant

Comment: yes you are true I need artificially click this button and trigger this function

Comment: why I got minus? I am just looking to solve my problem

Comment: You need to explain your problem more clearly.  You don't seem to differentiate between running code, triggering events, and attaching a callback to an event through an event listener. Because of this, your wording is contradictory and difficult to answer without ambiguity. You're asking us to teach you the basics of javascript.

Comment: Plus you mention javascript and php. Both are "code" and people are assuming you mean javascript code will trigger the click because it doesn't work that way from php. Are they right?

Comment: I just want to learn something do what you want

Comment: suggest you post more code or write a clearer question.

Comment: What you now have will work fine, although it is a stylistic oddity. In JavaScript, you can trigger a function without using jQuery. jQuery's `trigger` method is triggers both a jQuery event handler, and a Document Object Model event on an HTML element, but the code you want to run doesn't necessarily need to be triggered through the DOM -- you can just use JavaScript. (E.g. `myMethod = function() { $("#panel").slideToggle("slow"); }` and then later `myMethod()` to run the code.)

Comment: thanks a lot benastan it works as I needed

Answer (score 3):

`$(selector).click()` triggers the click event on all items selected.

Answer (score 1):

To trigger a click..use `.trigger()`

```
$(".btn-slide").trigger("click");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/4LwLT/1/ (on page load you'll see the `slideUp()` occur, and the CSS toggle)